# Как растянуть изображение до оригинальных размеров в таблице markdown?

Tags: html, markdown

Есть `markdown` разметка, в которой слишком маленькая картинка

```
|Пн|Вт|Ср|Чт|Пт|Сб|Вс|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|1<br>9|2<br>14|3<br>4+4+3+3+2=16|4: 9+8+7+7+6=37|5<br> 5+4+4+3+3=19|6<br>10+9+8+7+7=41|7|
|8<br>11+9+9+8+7=44|9|10<br>10|11<br>43|12|13<br>5+4+4+3+3=19|14<br>20+8+8=36|
|15<br>6+5+4+4+3=22|16<br>7+6+5+5+4=27|17<br>6+5+5+4+4=24|18<br>|19:7+6+6+5+7=31|20:10|21<br>8+7+6+6+5=32|
|22|23<br>5+4+4+3+3=19|24<br>17|25<br>|26:|27:<br><div><img src="images/wallpapers-nature-2.jpg"/></div>|28:|
|29|30|31|1|2|3|4|
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я добавляю тег `pre` с пробелами, то картинка растягивается. Чем больше пробелов, тем сильнее

```
|Пн|Вт|Ср|Чт|Пт|Сб|Вс|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|1<br>9|2<br>14|3<br>4+4+3+3+2=16|4: 9+8+7+7+6=37|5<br> 5+4+4+3+3=19|6<br>10+9+8+7+7=41|7|
|8<br>11+9+9+8+7=44|9|10<br>10|11<br>43|12|13<br>5+4+4+3+3=19|14<br>20+8+8=36|
|15<br>6+5+4+4+3=22|16<br>7+6+5+5+4=27|17<br>6+5+5+4+4=24|18<br>|19:7+6+6+5+7=31|20:10|21<br>8+7+6+6+5=32|
|22|23<br>5+4+4+3+3=19|24<br>17|25<br>|26:|27:<pre>                                                                                                                                                                                                                         </pre><br><div><img src="images/wallpapers-nature-2.jpg"/></div>|28:|
|29|30|31|1|2|3|4|
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы получить оригинальный размер картинки в таблице без подбора количества пробелов в тег `pre`?

Comment: На чистом маркдауне боюсь никак. Только если у вас есть доступ к стилям получаемого в результате html. Или если у вас расширенный маркдаун как на гитхабе, у которого можно что-нибудь вроде `![](myimg.jpg){width:100%}` такого

Comment: Боюсь `width:100%` для таблицы не сработал(

Comment: Но при этом html разметку использовать можно (ту которую позволяет `md`), к сожалению я ее для своей задачи применить не смог, только тег `pre`, который ну уж слишком костыльно выглядит

Comment: Может инлайн стили работают? Попробуйте тогда `<img src="..." style="width:100%">`

Comment: Неа, вот результат https://imgur.com/a/vqR0FMd